# setHidden() on child of QTableWidgetItem

Tags: c++, qt

I am stuck with a piece of code where I need to hide a few children of a `QTreeWidgetItem`.

Now I googled a bit and found out that I need to add the item to view first before calling `setHidden()` on the child but I am confused about this. I need help with "adding to view".

My code goes like:

```
QTreeWidgetItem *item = memData->topLevelGroupBox->treeWidget()->topLevelItem(0);
item->child(currentIndex)->setHidden(true);
```

Comment: Your question is not good stated. Title says `setHidden ... QTableWidgetItem`, question is about `adding to view`, code uses `QTreeWidgetItem`... Do you try to add a QTreeWidgetItem to a table?

Comment: @user1810087 No, I did not. As the treeWidget is already available. I am only accessing it. So what should be the approach to hide a few children of this item?

Comment: Please rephrase your question, to make it more clear. You usually don't need to add the item before hidding it. QTreeWdgetItem has a method `setHidden`. In your case it should look like `item->setHidden(true);`. Adding items to a QTreeWidget you have several options: `addTopLevelItem`, `insertTopLevelItem`, `setCurrentItem`, ... take a look into the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html)